# Show only last overlay in beamer for a single frame

Tags: beamer, overlays

Is there an overlay specification for `\frame<...>{` that yields the last version of the frame if the frame is built with relative overlays?

The handout version achieves this, but sets it globally. I'm looking for a frame-specific solution. I think it works (not elegantly) with `\frame<N>{` for some sufficiently large `N`.

Comment: Note that `\frame` is only provided for compatibility with old documents, it was superseeded by `\begin{frame} <content> \end{frame}`, see section 8.1 footnote 1 of the `beameruserguide`

Answer (score -1):

Not sure what you mean by overlay (`\pause`, `\only`, `\uncover`, ...), but it is possible to modify the behaviour of the command before a specific frame, and restore it right after. For instance:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{frame1}
First sentence
\pause
Second one
\pause
etc...
\end{frame}

\let\savepausebehaviour=\pause 
\def\pause{} 
\begin{frame}{frame2}
First sentence
\pause
Second one
\pause
etc...
\end{frame}
\let\pause=\savepausebehaviour

\begin{frame}{frame3}
First sentence
\pause
Second one
\pause
etc...
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Frames 1 and 3 use the default behaviour of pause, while frame 2 behaves like there is no `\pause`.

Comment: To clarify my question: If I had absolute overlay specification such as `<3-5,8>` on say `\item`s then I can freeze my frame at a given overlay counter. For relative overlay specifications there is a similar hidden counter that increments by `+` or `\pause`. With `\frame<N>` I can still freeze my frame (or replay it with `\againframe<N>{label}`). Is there a direct way of getting the last counter for a frame? Note that I might also have a `<+>` element that is not on the last version of my frame. So just disabling the `\pause` does not answer my question.